# A variant of Ore condition in Hamilton graph

Tags: graph-theory

Let G(V,E) be a simple graph of order n and δ the minimum degree of vertices. Suppose that the degree sum of any pair
of nonadjacent vertices is at least n and F ⊂ E with |F| ≤ ⌊δ−2⌋/2. Let G − F be the graph obtained from G by deleting the edges in F . Prove that
(1) G − F is connected and (2) G − F is Hamiltonian.

Actually, it was a problem in S.T.Yau contest. I'm trying to solve this...

Comment: Wait！This was a problem in that contest in 2013. I'm not cheating in an exam！